# Facebook API images not added to post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to make a post to FB page with images.

It looks like this:

**First create image:**

```
$res = Http::post(
        env("FB_API") .
            'my-page-id' .
            "/photos?access_token=" .
            'my-access-token',
        [
            "url" => 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/DAOSdaS9ed3GPsJlAmqw',
        ]
    );
```

**Response:**

```
"{"id":"52305359978858","post_id":"31457605812596_523305373312190"}"
```

**Then I make the actual post call:**

```
    $id = json_decode($res->body())->id;

    $uri =
        env("FB_API") .
        'my-page-id' .
        "/feed?access_token=" .
        'my-access-token'.
        '&attached_media[0]={"media_fbid":"'.$id.'"}';


    $res = Http::post($uri, [
        'message' => "test"
    ]);
```

**But I keep getting this error:**

> "{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has
> occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"ARajcZtA7tWcd05G5V71pr"}}"

This is strange because when I post without image it's working.

The scopes my token has:

```
pages_read_engagement,
pages_manage_posts,
pages_show_list,
instagram_basic,
instagram_content_publish,
instagram_manage_comments
```

Comment: Where exactly did you find an `attached_media` parameter? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#pubfields doesn't mention it.

Comment: @CBroe right here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/

Comment: Okay. But it should be a POST parameter then, rather than getting appended to the URL query string.

Comment: When I change it to this I get the same: 

```$res = Http::post($uri, ['message' => "test lars", 'attached_media' => [$id]]);```

Comment: Looks like now you'd be sending a plain id, instead of wrapping it into a JSON object under the `media_fbid` property name.

Comment: Yes tried that but then the response is:

```{"error":{"message":"(#100) param attached_media must be an array.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Aj92wQvk6P8Xjik78FrOGTL"}}```

Comment: It needs to be an _array_ of _objects_.

Comment: Ah yes sorry about that. Thanks now it works!